# How not to display DetailNoObjectsAvailable view via mobile?

Tags: sapui5, master-detail

I've created a sapui5 project from master-detail template. What I want to achieve is showing an empty list (which is in the master view) via mobile without navigating to DetailNoObjectsAvailable view. I just can't find where DetailNoObjectsAvailable view is called from.

The reason why I want to achieve this is that when there are no objects in the list in the beginning and then an object is added to odata source, I see nothing but 'No objects available' and I can not navigate to the master list to refresh it manually. I have to refresh the whole page in fiori client browser to see it. When the list is not empty in the beginning and I add an object to odata source, the list refreshes automatically and I face no problems seeing it.

I haven't changed anything in the routing definition:

```js
"routes": [
 {
  "pattern": "",
  "name": "master",
  "target": [
   "object",
   "master"
  ]
 }, {
  "pattern": "visitors_view/{objectId}",
  "name": "object",
  "target": [
   "master",
   "object"
  ]
 }
],
"targets": {
 "master": {
  "viewName": "Master",
  "viewLevel": 1,
  "viewId": "master",
  "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
 },
 "object": {
  "viewName": "Detail",
  "viewId": "detail",
  "viewLevel": 2
 },
 "detailObjectNotFound": {
  "viewName": "DetailObjectNotFound",
  "viewId": "detailObjectNotFound"
 },
 "detailNoObjectsAvailable": {
  "viewName": "DetailNoObjectsAvailable",
  "viewId": "detailNoObjectsAvailable"
 },
 "notFound": {
  "viewName": "NotFound",
  "viewId": "notFound"
 }
}
```

Comment: Pls show your routing definition in your `manifest.json`

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the routing definition. Added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism routing to the notFoundobject is found in manifest.json:

manifest.json: bypassed + target in routing config

```
 "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "test.test.view",
                "controlId": "layout",
                "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages",
                "bypassed": {
                    -------> "target": "notFound" <--------
                },
                "async": true
            },



"targets": {
                "notFound": {
                    "viewName": "NotFound",
                    "viewId": "notFound"
                }
            }
```

View in webapp/view:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="test.test.controller.NotFound"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <MessagePage
        id="page"
        title="{i18n>notFoundTitle}"
        text="{i18n>notFoundText}"
        icon="sap-icon://document">
    </MessagePage>
</mvc:View>
```

That is what you are looking for right?

Maybe your problem is solved by changing from "target": "notFound" to "target": "master" within the bypassed section in manifest.json.

UPDATE: Detail.controller.js

```
_onBindingChange : function () {
            var oView = this.getView(),
                oElementBinding = oView.getElementBinding();

            // No data for the binding
            if (!oElementBinding.getBoundContext()) {
                this.getRouter().getTargets().display("detailObjectNotFound");  <------------
                // if object could not be found, the selection in the master list
                // does not make sense anymore.
                this.getOwnerComponent().oListSelector.clearMasterListSelection();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: PS: for mobile adaptions use search to conditionally switch things for a certain device. But I think manifest.json is a global setting. On view-level you could apply changes only to mobile devices. Check this https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.5/docs/guide/d63a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2.html

Comment: "notFound" is not the view I'm interested in. When there are no objects in the list, it navigates to "DetailNoObjectsAvailable" view. I can't find where it is stated in the code. This view is not mentioned neither in manifest.json, nor in master controller, nor in listSelector controller...

Comment: in detail.controller I change my response. hope this helps.

Comment: "detailObjectNotFound" is also not the view I am talking about:) it's "detailNoObjectsAvailable"

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem by commenting some lines in ListSelector.js. They caused an error in the console, which in its turn was the cause of my problem:

```js
constructor : function () {
 this._oWhenListHasBeenSet = new Promise(function (fnResolveListHasBeenSet) {
  this._fnResolveListHasBeenSet = fnResolveListHasBeenSet;
 }.bind(this));
 this.oWhenListLoadingIsDone = new Promise(function (fnResolve, fnReject) {
  this._oWhenListHasBeenSet
   .then(function (oList) {
    oList.getBinding("items").attachEventOnce("dataReceived",
     function (oData) {
      if (!oData.getParameter("data")) {
       fnReject({
        list : oList,
        error : true
       });
      }
      var oFirstListItem = this.getFirstListItem();
      if (oFirstListItem) {
       fnResolve({
        list : oList,
        firstListitem : oFirstListItem
       });
      } 
      // else {
      //  fnReject({
      //   list : oList,
      //   error : false
      //  });
      //}
     }.bind(this)
    );
   }.bind(this));
 }.bind(this));
},
```

Comment: I'm still interested where detailNoObjectsAvailable route is called from